# Navigating to another screen without bottomNavigationBar Icons in flutter but keeping the bottomNavigationBar in anotherScreen

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview

I have a `main.dart` with bottomNavigationBar with 5 tabs and when clicked on tabs it goes to the respective pages.

```
void main() => runApp(MyStatefulWidget());

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    ProfilePage1(),
    EventPage3(),
    HomePage2(),
    AllEventPage(),
    ProfilePage1(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<EventModifier>(
            create: (context) => EventModifier()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

        home: Scaffold(
          body: Center(child: _children.elementAt(_selectedIndex)),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("")),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), title: Text("")),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.account_circle,
                    size: 45,
                    color: Color(0xFF334192),
                  ),
                  title: Text("")),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.message), title: Text("")),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.table_chart), title: Text("")),
            ],
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedItemColor: Color(0xFF334192),
            unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now, in the 3rd tab there is a button called "See All" and when clicked it should go to the 4th page **With bottomNavigationBar** and automatically it should be clicked the 4th tab of the bottomNavigationBar. 
How to do that in flutter?flutt

Comment: I hope my answer below answers your questions. If it’s useful, please take a second to accept and upvote it. Otherwise please let me know what you need clarification on

Answer (score 0):

To change the bottomNavigationBar selected item manually you would set

```
_selectedIndex = 4;
```

To navigate to the AllEventTab when the ‘See All’ button is clicked... one way is using Navigator.push() in the button’s onPressed(), like this:

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AllEventTab()),
  );
}
```

see [“Navigation Basics”](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)